# Get const visibility in PHP

Tags: reflection, php-7.1

Since PHP 7.1, they introduced const visibility, and I need to read it thorugh reflection. I went as far as creating my `ReflectionClass` like this:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass(static::class);
```

The function `getConstants()` returns a name/value map and `getConstant($name)` just its value. Both doesn't return visibility information. Shouldn't there be a `ReflectionConst` class similarly to functions, properties, etc.?

Is there any other way to obtain this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection changes for this are touched on in [the feature's RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/class_const_visibility), though I don't know if they've been documented elsewhere yet.

The new class is `ReflectionClassConstant` with relevant methods (among others):

- `isPublic()`
- `isPrivate()`
- `isProtected()`

`ReflectionClass` has two new methods:

- `getReflectionConstants()` - returns an array of ReflectionClassConstants
- `getReflectionConstant()` - retrieves a ReflectionClassConstant by name

---

Example:

```
class Foo
{
    private const BAR = 42;
}

$r = new ReflectionClass(Foo::class);

var_dump(
    $r->getReflectionConstants(),
    $r->getReflectionConstant('BAR')->isPrivate()
);
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(ReflectionClassConstant)#2 (2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "BAR"
    ["class"]=>
    string(3) "Foo"
  }
}
bool(true)
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks! I wish that the fact that they're not documented anywhere would surprise me, but it doesn't.

Comment: It already is documented, see PHP manual for ex. http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getreflectionconstant.php